# Getting clear kinect depth data

Tags: ros, kinect, opencv2, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros node and getting topic with

```
sub = nh.subscribe("/camera/depth/image", 1, &Subscribe_Depth::callback, this);
```

and convert to opencv

```
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(im, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1);
```

I am getting kinect depth data but it is too noisy and shaded image. How do ı clean them from image.Is opencv is good way? How else can I do? Any link or code? (I study on ubuntu and use c++ language )

Thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198037/getting-clear-kinect-depth-data/) by [Aylin COŞKUN](https://answers.ros.org/users/5381/aylin-co%C5%9Fkun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, there is no magic "get all noise and shades away" method for kinect data. Both are basically caused by the sensing principle, so in some way somebody has to cope with them. For reducing shades maybe inpainting may help http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html?highlight=inpaint#cv2.inpaint; for reducing noise maybe gaussian blur may help, http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#cv2.GaussianBlur; http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#cv2.blur; However, in both cases you have to be very careful that you to not "blur away" real features in the image so that it may "look nicer" but you really have lost information. If you want to do some processing on the image, maybe you should try to accept the image has contains some noise and try to use the shades as features....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aylin COŞKUN](https://answers.ros.org/users/5381/aylin-co%C5%9Fkun/) on 2014-11-24**:
I will look at them. when ı use opencv the range of kinect is 5 m but my view is not detected after about 1.5 m.  I have searched ros with kinect, ı found `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image` . This line gives good result. Can I get results like this?